# SSIS importing ragged right flat file

Tags: ssis

I am very new to SSIS development. Please help me

I have a ragged right flat file with no column names, which I need to import to sql server database. 
The problem is, when importing these file using flat file connection manager, all the columns are stored as varchar. I have different columns like Amount (which should be a decimal data type), percentage (which should be a decimal data type), Date (which should be a date data type mm/dd/yyyy format).

For example, The amount field is loaded as 000012347834 . I need to change it to 123478.34 
percentage field is loaded as 03246. I need it as 03.246 .
How can I do these conversions using SSIS.

Thank you in advance for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the advanced editor on your connection manager to change the data types.

You can also use a data conversion task which is more along the lines of what SSIS is designed for... Transform is the T in ETL.

However most often if I have a lot of conversions to do on a text file import I will load into a staging table with all varchar and use a stored procedure to do the conversions.